# Undefined variable laravel 7

Tags: laravel, variables, undefined, laravel-7

I keep getting

> Undefined variable: products

products.blade

```
@foreach ($products as $prod)
    <td>{{ $prod->name }} </td>
    <td>{{ $prod->buying_price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $prod->selling_price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $prod->weight}}</td>
@endforeach
```

products controller

```
public function index()
{
    $products = products::all();
    return view('products.products')->with('products', $products);
}
```

i also tried

```
public function index()
{
    $products = products::all();
    return view ('products.products',compact('products'));
    
}
```

route

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
```

Comment: Use `dd($products)` after `$products = products::all();` to see what it contains. Do you have a model `products`?

Comment: `return view('products.products')->with(compact('products'));`

Comment: yes i have a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should make sure you didn't make any typos. As seen from the code you provided it should just work, as long as you have the `products` model.

Normally how Laravel works is you have a route, in your case that's `url.test/products` which is bound to some function in the `ProductsController`. You haven't provided the method within the route. Maybe that could be it. Normally the route would look something similar to this:

`Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@index')->name('projects');`

Or in Laravel 8 it would look like this:

`Route::get('/projects/all', [App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'index'])->name('projects');`

Then your index function within the controller should look similar to this. In that case there is nothing wrong with your code above

```
$projects = Project::all();

return view('projects', compact('projects'));
```

And you should be able to call `$projects` within your view. Also try to see if `$projects` is even full. Just do `dd($projects)` within your controller so make sure it returns something.

I suggest you to go over the whole process again to see if you made any typos or mistakes that may cause this situation as your code above is perfectly fine except for not giving the right function in the route.

EDIT:

I can see now, you spelt [product] wrong. It is supposed to be [Product] as you’re calling the Product model.

Comment: thank you , i solved it by adding   <?php
            use App\Products;
            $products = Products::all();
           ?>                                                                             before foreach loop

Comment: Could you accept my answer as solved please?